# CoreData detect database inconsistency on start up

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, magicalrecord

We have some code to determine if there is no database file currently created. If this is the case, we do some initialization routines to populate the user's database based on some files that may exist on the file system (basically a migration routine).

The routine is basically like this

```
NSURL * defaultStorePath = [NSPersistentStore MR_defaultLocalStoreUrl];
BOOL initializeDatabase = ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[defaultStorePath path]];    

[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreAtURL:defaultStorePath];

if(initializeDatabase)
    // ... ingest user files ...
```

So this works well if the `.sqlite` file is not present. However if the `.sqlite-wal` or `.sqlite-shm` files are missing/corrupt, we can't find a way to detect this scenario.

We would like to do a data integrity check or something in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `MagicalRecord`:

```
NSURL *storeURL = ...
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];

if (persistentStore) {
    // further initialization
} else {
    switch (error.code) {
        case NSFileReadCorruptFileError: {
            NSLog(@"database corrupted.");
            // delete .sqlite, -wal and -shm
            // make another attempt to add persistent store
            break;
        }
        case NSPersistentStoreIncompatibleVersionHashError: {
            NSLog(@"database model updated.");
            // migrate
            break;
        }
        default: {
            NSLog(@"unresolved error %@", error.localizedDescription);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe we can file a feature request with MagicalRecord to help us handle failures. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, and I hope it will be helpful.

```
func configurePersistentStore() {
    let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    nc.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.dataBaseWillBeRecreated(_:)), name:kMagicalRecordPSCMismatchWillDeleteStore, object:nil)

    MagicalRecord.setLoggingLevel(MagicalRecordLoggingLevel.Warn)
    // if sqlite database does not match the model you provided, delete store.
    // MagicalRecord.setShouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch(true)
    MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed(kPersistentStoreName)

    if ESGlobal.sharedInstance().firstRun { // User first run your app after installation.
        self.fillDefaultDataToSQLiteDB() // fill data
    }
}
```